# WordPress: only built plugin GPL licensed

Tags: gpl, commercial, plugins

We are developing WordPress plugins. As WordPress itself is GPL licensed we must publish our plugin as GPL, too. Our complete plugin development environment is built on top of a lot of `devDependencies` and `dependencies` (npm with `package.json`). I did some tests with https://www.npmjs.com/package/licensee and the output gave me also dependencies licensed under `CC-BY-3.0` and `CC-BY-4.0`.

The above mentioned CC dependencies are only represent in `devDependencies`, that means, the code of that dependencies are only used for building the plugin. In our CI/CD pipeline we get an installable and uploadable `.zip` file with the WordPress plugin itself as artifact.

- Is the build process itself (e. g `webpack`, `babel` or `typescript`) relevant for the built WordPress plugin? Can I differentiate between licensing of `dependencies` and `devDependencies`? Do I need to make the build process also GPL?
- I need to put a file like `3RD_PARTY_LICENSES` to the built artifact. Do I need to refer to all used dependencies (inclusive `devDependencies`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For copyright licensing, only the dependencies of the deployed software are relevant. The licenses on your build tools can be completely ignored<sup>1</sup>.

A file like `3RD_PARTY_LICENSES` also only needs to refer to the licenses of your `dependencies`.

<sup>1: the exception here are tools that copy part of their source into the output. Those would effectively be a dependency of the deployed software.</sup>

Comment: Well technically the copyright of the tools does matter, but only insofar as you copy (i.e. install) them. For example, a proprietary tool T that compiles your software might say in its license agreement "you are allowed to install this software on 5 machines" and so you are allowed to do that. If you install it on 6 machines you could be said to be violating the license and/or copyright of T. But if you use that software (1 illegal copy on 6th machine) to create your own program P, then the distribution of P itself is not violating the copyright or license of T.